Cannot encrypt/decrypt value for secure store
We are facing issues while logging in to the application. It throws an error message stating, "Cannot encrypt/decrypt value for secure store." These issues are occurring only on lower-end Android devices with Android versions 7, 8, and 10. Sometimes the application works perfectly, but randomly, in rare cases, if we install and uninstall and reinstall the APK, the error occurs during login.
On iOS devices, the application works perfectly without any issues, regardless of whether the device is old or new. However, for older Android devices, we are encountering this issue.
Clearing the app cache and data resolves the issue, but it is not practical to expect users to do this. We have also attempted to clear all the keys stored in secure storage before calling the login API, but unfortunately, this has not resolved the issue.
Our application is developed using React Native CLI, and we are utilizing AsyncStorage for data storage.
We have also attempted to clear all the keys stored in secure storage before calling the login API. Additionally, we use native code to delete all cache data, but unfortunately, it has not resolved the issue. for such older devices The login  functions works properly if the user manually clears the app cache and data from the app info settings. Is there any solution for this? We have been struggling with this issue for over a month.

Have you created an issue in the asyncstorage's issue tracker? Anyway your post is missing a stack trace of the error you get. Without a stack trace it is often very difficult to identify where the problem is located.
